# error message when running an application on Bonita tool

Tags: bonita

I am trying to run this form in the browser, but I keep getting this message not sure how to fix it so can you help me please.

"Ui Designer form type is selected and no target form is defined for overview page mapping. an autogenerated form will be used in the development environment ONLY"

here is a screen shoot of the message.
/Users/user/Desktop/Screen Shot 2017-08-03 at 5.31.44 pm.png
/Users/user/Desktop/Screen Shot 2017-08-03 at 6.34.41 pm.png

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatly I cant see any pics from your problem and I just think your problem might be with deploying your process.

As the error mentions the form you see when you Run the process from studio is an autogenerated form for testing the process in development mode(Obvious)

So if you want to deploy your process on a deployed Bonita BPM engin you have to create all those forms.

Select the Task (containing the contract cause forms are only generated for contracts) --> Under details panel ---> Execution Tab ---> Form :

Here you have 4 options and as it seems your new to Bonita so I suggest that you go with the UI Designer cause **it will generate a form for deploying** , simply choose UI Designer then from the right side of Target Form text area click the pencil icon (Edit) , it will create a new form for your contract and opens UI Designer to modify it.

If you just want to see how your process works in deployment environment and don't want to spend time on designing the UI just change the form name from "newForm" to what you want (All the forms created by UI Designer have the "newForm" name before you change it and it may cause problems if you don't modify the name ) and save it.
Build your project and deploy it.